# Windows Forms OpenFileDialog, prevent opening instance if dialog already showing

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I have an OpenFileDialog instance on my class, like this.

```
public MyClass
{
    public OpenFileDialog Dialog { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        Dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    }

    public void ShowDialog()
    { 
        if (Dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            DoStuff(Dialog.FileNames);
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that if I spam click the button to open the dialog 3 times, the dialog will pop open once. Once I close the first dialog, it will show it an additional two times. Is there any way I can detect if the dialog is already showing to prevent popping it open?

Edit: I am also using this from a unity3d experience utilizing the Mono version of System.Windows.Forms. Because of this, there really isn't a form "Owning" the dialog, it is the unity game window. The button pushed is a GUI element inside the game.

Thanks

Comment: Well, that is not supposed to happen.  The dialog should disable the window that owns the button so you cannot click it again.  Very unclear how that happened but it is fairly important that you use the ShowDialog(owner) overload so you don't leave it up to the class to find an owner.  It might pick the wrong one and then you have this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Dialog.ShowDialog(this);
```

Assuming here that `this` is he form which contains the button.  This should display the dialog as a modal with the form as it's owner preventing you from activating or using controls on that form until the dialog is dismissed.